# How to client side realtime validate a form with select, radio, checkbox, text, file input, just use javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a user config page with many inputs of a form. I want to realtime validate the input to avoid format error when user types in the text input, check filename and pop some info when user types in the select, radio, checkbox input.
I just want to know with method shuold I use for each type input on the above for.

Comment: Look for `onchange` events on each of the inputs, selects, etc. Write JS function for validating each of the inputs.

Comment: can i use onclick with the clickable input?

Comment: Yes, but I see no point in doing so. Try looking here for example - http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate/ - it may give You the point how to validate forms.

Comment: yeah, it's really a good resource of validating each input type, but I'm resolving to a realtime evt

Comment: will you briefly explain the difference between onchange and onclick here,

Comment: Then You don't need the `onsubmit` event on the whole `<form>`, but `onchange` and similar events on each `<input>`, `<select>` etc.

Comment: the onclick is applyed to the clickable input, as checkbox, select, radio, not include the submit

Comment: and the onchange is after the text input  lose focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write a logic that will do the validation for you. Once you've written it, you can use `keyup` event of jquery that will call that function as soon as you type something.

For example, the snippet below will do real time validations as soon as you begin typing. If the typed text consists of only alphabets, then there will be no error (and if there's any, then it will go away) and as soon as you have typed any number, it will show error.

```js
$("#only-text").on("keyup", function() {
  realTimeValidate();
});

function realTimeValidate() { 
    var inputField = document.getElementById("only-text").value;
  
    if(!isAlphaOrParen(inputField))
      document.getElementById("showerror").innerHTML = "Please enter only numbers";
    else 
      document.getElementById("showerror").innerHTML = "";
}
      
function isAlphaOrParen(str) {
  return /^[a-zA-Z()]+$/.test(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Type only Text (error will be generated if you type a number) : <br><input id="only-text" type="text"/><br>
<span id="showerror" style="color:red"></span>
```

Comment: yeah, it seems good, i'll have a try. how about other input type?

Comment: for `type="radio`, `type="select"` and `type="checkbox"`, you can use javascript's `onchange="yourFunction()"`. There are loads of ways in which you can do these things. Just Google `"input onchange realtime event"`

Comment: with these input type you refered above, can i use onclick to replace of onchange

Comment: It's upto you, you can use it. Apart from these mentioned above, there's are lots and lots of other ways also.... like using jQuery or angularjs.